# Working with new object changes reference too

Tags: java, reference, libgdx

I have this list of objects that includes an array i (want) to use just as reference. So when i create a new object, fill it with an array in the list and start changing that new object i do not want my initial arrays for the object in my list to change.

I basically do this:

```
//Fill list with my reference objects;

Object newObject = new Object(); //So i do not change the previous newObject in the loop.
newObject = (find)ObjectFromList;
newObject.array = RotateArray(newObject.array);
```

If i fill another newObject with the same object from the list it already is rotated. I hope i have been clear enough. Below a shortened version of my code, still a bit messy too:

LoadRooms(); //Loads all the objects and arrays from a file into the list.

```
for(int x=0;x<width;x++)
        {
            for(int y=0;y<height;y++)
            {
                Room newRoom = new Room();
                //Fill newroom with correct room type, rotate and build tilemap.
                //Dead ends
                if(!mazeMap[x][y].N && !mazeMap[x][y].E && mazeMap[x][y].S && !mazeMap[x][y].W)
                {
                    newRoom = FindRoom(Room.RoomType.DeadEnd);
                    newRoom.room = TurnRoomCW(newRoom.room);
                    newRoom.room = TurnRoomCW(newRoom.room);
                    newRoom.room = TurnRoomCW(newRoom.room);
                }
                else if(!mazeMap[x][y].N && mazeMap[x][y].E && !mazeMap[x][y].S && !mazeMap[x][y].W)
                {
                    newRoom = FindRoom(Room.RoomType.DeadEnd);
                }
                            //Etc, etc then i build a map from the newRoom.room array        
    }
}
```

This is what TurnRoom() looks like:

```
private String[][] TurnRoomCW(String[][] room)
    {
        String[][] rotatedRoom = new String[room[0].length][room.length];
        for (int y = 0; y < room[0].length;y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0;x < room.length;x++)
            {
                rotatedRoom[y][x] = room[7 - x][y];
            }
        }       
        return rotatedRoom;
    }
```

and here is FindRoom

```
private Room FindRoom(Room.RoomType roomType)
    {
        Collections.shuffle(rooms, rand);
        for (Room r : rooms)
        {
            if (r.roomType.equals(roomType))
                return r;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

When i want to turn something like a corner type room, say NE into the correct position all other rooms turn with it. So when i want to turn, say SW into position the NE will be position wrong again.

Comment: No, I'm sorry: you haven't been clear enough. A simple exposition of your problem, without redundant code would be a better start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FindRoom` method is returning a reference to the actual room.
'TurnRoomCW' returns a new object, but you then assign that new object back into the original room

So your problem is right here:

```
newRoom = FindRoom(Room.RoomType.DeadEnd); // 1) find a DeadEnd room
newRoom.room = TurnRoomCW(newRoom.room); // 2) create rotated room, assign it to the room from step 1)
```

If you want to work with a new `Room` object, you will need to create a new one somehow. For example, you might define a constructor for `Room` that returns a new object initialized from an existing one. For example,

```
/** copy constructor */
public Room(Room oldRoom) { 
   this(); // regular constructor
   this.room = oldRoom.room.clone(); // new Room gets its own array!
   this.roomType = oldRoom.roomType;
   // … etc for any other member variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Java objects are references (pointers if you prefer), so unless you make an explicit copy of an Array (or any other object), it will point to the same object.

If you want to avoid that, you have to do a clone first:

```
List myList = referenceList.clone();
```

This is generally a good habit anyway to avoid having your "internal" object being modified by the external world.

Comment: I will try that. But why: int i = 10; int j = i; j - 1; now i is still 10 and j is 9. I am doing the same in my code afaik.

Comment: I have no access to the clone method. I am using ArrayList.

Comment: ArrayList is cloneable (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). The other option is something like : newList = new ArrayList(referenceList);